# OutlinedTextField Label always top

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am beginner on Jetpack Compose. I use outlinedtextfield. How to show label always on top, when text is empty or not.

Comment: There's no such default implementation as of now.

Comment: can you show an image of how you would like it to behave? Most things on compose can be easily achievable by just composing elements.